# View a picture in datagridview from MS Access database

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have an Access database with pictures and other data stored. I want to show the picture from the database in a DatagridView.

This works but the image height is very small in the DatagridView. I also want to stretch the image.

How do I do this ?

Here is where I bind the data from the Access database to the datagridview:

```
conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, conn);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(table);

DatagridView1.DataSource = table;

conn.Close();
```

With this code I created a column to show the picture, but I can't bind the data from the database to this column.

```
DataGridViewImageColumn photoColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
photoColumn.DataPropertyName = "Photo";
photoColumn.Width = 200;
photoColumn.HeaderText = "Image";
photoColumn.ReadOnly = true;
photoColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;

DatagridView1.Columns.Add(photoColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data of your database are bind by the fist code segment you have written, speciffically:

```
DatagridView1.DataSource = table;
```

binds the data brought by your query to your Datagridview. All you have to do is to set up the query accordingly to retrieve the image.

Franlky with Dataadapter I am not quite sure how to store an image but if you use Sqlreader:
...

```
if (reader.HasRows)
    {
      while (reader.Read())
     {
         string s1 = reader[0].ToString(); ///1st field you are interested
        string s2 = reader[1].ToString();  //2nd field you want
        byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[2]);   //your photo image
      }
     }
```

Finally be sure, to set on the designer `AutogenerateColumns` property to `true` for your `Datagrid`.